# Cypress, drag and drop images or video using attachFile()

Tags: image, upload, cypress

I've tried various ways to get Cypress using attachFile() to either drag and drop or attach an image or video file. As you may see on the Cypress failure image attached, it doesn't load the image to the Modal box, the add button remains disabled and the test fails.

#1

```
Cypress.Commands.add('uploadMedia', (mediaType) => {
cy.wait(2000)
const fileName = 'Cover.jpg'
cy.fixture('Cover.jpg').then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
.then((fileContent) =>
{
    cy.get(newStoryPage.getDragAndDropFiles()).attachFile(
    {
        fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'image/jpg'},
        {subjectType: 'drag-n-drop'
        
    })
})
```

***#2 I also tried this:***

```
cy.fixture('Cover.jpg').then(jpg => {
    const files = [
        { fileName: 'Cover.jpg', fileContent: jpg, mimeType: 'image/jpg' }
      ]

      newStoryPage.getDragAndDropFiles().attachFile(files, {subjectType: 'drag-n-drop', events: ['dragenter', 'drop'] })
    })
```

***#3 And tried this:***

```
Cypress.Commands.add('dropFile', {prevSubject: false}, (fileName) =>
{
            Cypress.log({name: 'dropFile'})
            
        return cy.fixture(fileName, 'base64').then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob).then((blob) =>
        {
            return cy.window().then((win) =>
            {
                const file = new win.File([blob], fileName)
                const dataTransfer = new win.DataTransfer()
                dataTransfer.items.add(file)
                return cy.document().trigger('drop', {dataTransfer})

            })
        })
    }
)
```

return

> return get function of ui drag and drop area:

```
    class NewStoryPage
getDragAndDropFiles() {
        return cy.get("div[class*='upload-file-ui']")}
```

***This class uses function #3 to run it:***

```
import NewStoryPage from '../../support/pageobjects/NewStoryPage'
const newStoryPage = new NewStoryPage()

class Create
{
uploadImage()
    {
        newStoryPage.getDragAndDropFiles().trigger('dragenter')
        cy.dropFile('Cover.jpg')
        newStoryPage.getAddButton().click()
    }
}
export default Create
```

html part:

```
    <div class="jsx-3861824103 upload-file-ui">
<span class="jsx-3993537252 icon">
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="jsx-3993537252">
<path d="M31.8 16.704c0 3.489-2.765 6.296-5.238 6.296H24v-1h2.562c1.92 0 4.238-2.362 4.238-5.296a5.359 5.359 0 0 0-3.607-5.097l-.407-.138-.581-.198-.087-.608-.06-.425A7.953 7.953 0 0 0 18.462 3.2a7.647 7.647 0 0 0-6.683 4.187l-.259.488-.37.696-.763-.197-.535-.138a3.474 3.474 0 0 0-.874-.13 2.943 2.943 0 0 0-3.024 2.766l-.022.404-.031.573-.51.262-.357.183A5.173 5.173 0 0 0 2.2 16.897c0 2.653 2.166 5.085 4.545 5.103H11v1H6.737C3.733 22.978 1.2 19.988 1.2 16.897a6.169 6.169 0 0 1 3.378-5.493l.357-.183.022-.402a3.93 3.93 0 0 1 4.022-3.713 4.432 4.432 0 0 1 1.125.162l.534.138.26-.488A8.645 8.645 0 0 1 18.462 2.2a8.956 8.956 0 0 1 8.584 7.897l.06.425.408.138a6.358 6.358 0 0 1 4.285 6.044zM18 14.707l2.646 2.646.707-.707-3.853-3.853-3.854 3.854.707.707L17 14.707V30h1z" class="jsx-3993537252">
</path>
</svg>
</span>
<div class="jsx-3861824103 upload-section">
<p class="jsx-3861824103 upload-title">Drag and drop a file here</p>
<div class="jsx-3861824103 upload-description">Only include media in your story that you have permission to use and will not violate copyright laws if published.<span class="jsx-3861824103">&nbsp;</span>
<a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" class="jsx-181317841" href="https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/terms-of-use.htm">
<span class="jsx-181317841">Learn more</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="jsx-4157471165 button default primary">Browse your files</button>
<p class="jsx-3861824103 upload-types">Supported file types: .jpg, .png, .gif, .svg</p>
</div>
```

[image: attachFile() DragAndDrop]

As you can see, I used various ways trying to add an image; but sadly I just can't get it to load. Any thoughts is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to solve it.
I was making my functions way more complicated than required. All I needed was the following:

```
            newStoryPage.getDragAndDropFiles().attachFile('image.jpg', 
            {
                subjectType: 'drag-n-drop', events: ['dragenter', 'drop']
            })
```

That was it! Lessoned learned, don't over complicate things! I hope this helps anyone else that is stuck with "attachFile()".